# How many tweets can be collected?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I'm a beginner at Twitter API. I'm going to do sentiment analysis for my paper. So I need to data(user's comments) from Twitter as much as possible.
However, I heard that Twitter's policy had changed last year. Its policy restrains that user collect a lot of data..

So I want to know how many tweets can be collected(ex. 5,000 data). Because if they restrain my access token, then I must change it. Also, I wonder it they restrict my access token or IP address.

I use Python with Anaconda, and program will conduct on workstation.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to collect tweets for specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to using [Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/basic-search.html), it said that

The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published **in the past 7 days**.

I have used this to collect tweets several months ago, it allows me to collect about 3000 tweets per user.

It is recommended to using [Streaming API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview.html).